# Ringer Mode iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have to get my default ringer mode (for example "Silent") and about this set the ringer mode later (for example if Silent i'll set "Vibrate") but i can't find right iOS services.
It's avaible this feature in iOS? how should i use for do this?

Comment: If you mean change ringtone programmatically, there's no public API for this so you can't.

Comment: ok, thank you! I'll remove this features in my app so...

Comment: @Nerkyator and what about brightness and wifi settings? it's possible change them?

Comment: `UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness` for screen brightness, no way to set wifi settings